# How to authorize user in multiple authentication scheme?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, ws-federation

I have implemented multiple authentication scheme under my .net core application.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(
            sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddWsFederation("AuthenticationScheme1", options =>
            {
                options.Wtrealm = tenantList.Find(m => m.TenantID == 1).Wtrealm;
                options.MetadataAddress = tenantList.Find(m => m.TenantID == 1).MetadataAddress;
            })
            .AddWsFederation("AuthenticationScheme2", options =>
            {
                options.Wtrealm = tenantList.Find(m => m.TenantID == 2).Wtrealm;
                options.MetadataAddress = tenantList.Find(m => m.TenantID == 2).MetadataAddress;
            });
```

I want to authorize specific users with specific scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the scheme want to authenticate based on user info from request body/header in a middleware :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //read userinfo from request body or header

    if ("xxx".Equals("allen@xx.com"))
    {
        var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync("YourSchemeName");
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;  
            return;
        }

    }
    ....

    await next();
});
```

Comment: Can I use `await context.AuthenticateAsync("YourSchemeName");` at controller side as i need to check it once only.

Comment: Try :`return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" } ,"YourSchemeName");`

Comment: I tried the challenge method to authenticate using specific schema and I'm able to redirect to specific schema successfully. 
But now the issue is that a RedirectUri which I specified under challenge is not getting any claims to authorize a user.